# Why does selecting a field change the Index Scan Type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As you can see from the picture:
Query1 and Query2 are equal in tables and where clauses.  But when I add a field from the Address table indexing goes from a Index Scan to a Table Scan.  My question is why?

**Note:** I see recommended index, but I do not think I have the authority to change the database.

[image]

Comment: Check about clustered index...

Answer (score 2):

This is more than likely happening because StateProvCode is not a column in the PK of the Address table, nor is it an INCLUDE column. So SQL Server must be determining that it would be cheaper to simply scan the table, instead of scanning the PK and then doing additional lookups in the Address table to get the value of StateProvCode for each row. It's possible that your performance won't suffer all that much because scanning an index might only be a little faster than scanning the table (unless you have a filtered index in place). Of course, as you can see, you probably need to create an index to really improve performance.

Comment: Agreed.  In a sense the index is another table optimised for certain searches.  If a required field is not covered by that index it is essentially joined to it's parent table *(Filter the index, join to the table, fetch the fields)*.  In this case the optimiser decided it would be cheaper to scan the whole table, rather than make use of the index but incur the cost of that addition "join".  That may be correct, but some times it isn't.  Perhaps you could check if all relevant statistics are up to date?  Or perhaps use a table hint to force use of the index and compare costs?